# How to retrieve properties that were instantiated by owl class instance in OWL API?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

Using the OWL API, I'm trying to check whether a sub-class has actually instantiated the object properties that set it apart from those it inherits from the parent class.

Is there a way to get the properties an instance has defined? My current approach is attempting to get the instances of an OWLClass as follows:

```
// OWLClass o_class <---valid OWLClass object (e.g. City, Capital, etc)
Set<OWLNamedIndividual> o_instances = reasoner.getInstances(o_class, true).getFlattened();
for (OWLNamedIndividual> inst : o_instances) {
    //get set of properties defined by each instance
}
```

I've tried a few different methods, to no avail. `inst.getObjectPropertiesInSignature()` returns nothing. An sample of one of the OWL files I'm using is shown below:

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="City">
    <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
            <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#hasAccommodation"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#LuxuryHotel"/>
    </owl:Restriction>
 </owl:Class>

 <owl:Class rdf:ID="Capital">
     <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
          <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Museums"/>
          <owl:onProperty>
            <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#hasActivity"/>
          </owl:onProperty>
        </owl:Restriction>
     </rdfs:subClassOf>
     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#City"/>
 </owl:Class>

<Capital rdf:ID="Canberra">
    <hasAccommodation rdf:resource="#FourSeasons"/>
</Capital>
<Capital rdf:ID="Sydney">
    <hasAccommodation rdf:resource="#FourSeasons"/>
    <hasActivity rdf:resource="#CoolMuseum"/>
</Capital>
```

In the example above, I'd like to be able to detect that `Canberra` **doesn't** use the property `hasActivity`, while `Sydney` does. I'm not sure how to properly obtain those properties and compare them. For brevity, I excluded the lines for the FourSeasons and Museum stuff. I hope I've explained this decently enough.

Comment: Have you tried using "getObjectPropertyValues(OWLOntology ontology)"? You can call that on your "inst" object.

Comment: @ChristianS Man, do I feel dumb right now. I think that is indeed what I'm looking for. When I initially saw that method's docs I think I misread it as returning a set of ranges. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: @ChristianS you should post as an answer so I can give you the credit for it

Comment: Indeed. In OWLAPI 4, those methods are available on EntitySearcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getObjectPropertyValues(OWLOntology ontology)` method which is provided by the OWLIndividual Interface. It will return a Map with `ObjectPropertyExpression` as key and a Set of `OWLIndivdual` as value.